# How does this js code leak memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I've been reading up on js best practices and common mistakes, and I came across this piece of code from https://www.toptal.com/javascript/10-most-common-javascript-mistakes

```
var theThing = null;
var replaceThing = function () {
    var priorThing = theThing;  // hold on to the prior thing
    var unused = function () {
        // 'unused' is the only place where 'priorThing' is referenced,
        // but 'unused' never gets invoked
        if (priorThing) {
            console.log("hi");
        }
    };
    theThing = {
        longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),  // create a 1MB object
        someMethod: function () {
            console.log(someMessage);
        }
    };
};
```

I tried entering this code into the console and calling `replaceThing()` multiple times and true enough, memory usage in Chrome task manager goes up even after GC.

The closure `unused` keeps a reference to priorThing, thus making it not eligible for GC. But:

1. when `priorThing = theThing` is executed, doesn't the reference in the `unused` closure change as well to `theThing` ?
2. even if #1 isn't the case, shouldn't the variable `unused` go out of scope anyway when execution of `replaceThing` finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes There is memory Leaking .This is beacause by the way closures are implemented in Javascript .Every function object has a link to a dictionary-style object representing its lexical scope. `IF A VARIABLE IS USED IN ONE CLOSURE, IT ENDS UP IN THE LEXICAL SCOPE SHARED BY ALL OTHER CLOSURES IN THAT SCOPE`. In this case we have two closures `theThing` and `unused` in the same scope. Using `priorThing` in `unused`, now that `priorThing` is a variable in a closure, much as `unused` is not called , will mean that `priorThing` is also in the scope of `theThing` closure. so `priorThing` will not be Garbage Collected after `replaceThing` returns.

1) When `priorThing = theThing` is executed the old `theThing` value is stored to `priorThing` so `unused` refers to the old `theThing` not the newly created one

Comment: I tried looking at the function scope in console. Is my understanding correct: when the someMethod closure in theThing is created, it keeps a reference to unused, which itself keeps a reference to priorThing. priorThing itself contains the previous version of someMethod, and to the previous version of unused, forming a chain of references back to the first object?

Comment: "IF A VARIABLE IS USED IN ONE CLOSURE, IT ENDS UP IN THE LEXICAL SCOPE SHARED BY ALL OTHER CLOSURES IN THAT SCOPE" can you please give me a link to that? I'd like to read more about it

Comment: http://info.meteor.com/blog/an-interesting-kind-of-javascript-memory-leak

Comment: You will get a very detailed explanation there..If you dnt understand it then contact me